# Getting unique values and casting to a string

Tags: python, pandas

How would I get the unique non-null values for the below data frame and cast it to a string? For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'language': 'en'}, {'id': 1}, {'id': 1, 'language': 'fr'}, {'id': 1, 'language': 'en'}])
```

I want to get:

```
       subs
1      'en,fr'
```

Currently I have something like:

```
summary_df = df.groupby(['field1', 'field2']).agg(
    subs                =('language', 'unique'),
).reset_index()
```

But it seems this has three problems:

- It includes nulls
- I cannot save this to sql since it returns an array (I guess I need a string for that)
- I also want it sorted

Here is what I'm currently doing. Is this approach good? bad? any places to improve?

```
subs =('burned_in_sub_language', lambda x: str(sorted(x.dropna().unique())))
```

Comment: `dfg = df.dropna().groupby('id').agg({'language': set})` or `dfg = df.dropna().groupby('id')['language'].apply(lambda col: ','.join(sorted(set(col))))`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thanks -- I just added an answer too -- does that approach look ok?

Comment: Using `str()` in that way, the result will be like `"['en' 'fr']"`.  You can do `dfg = df.groupby('id')['language'].apply(lambda col: ','.join(col.dropna().unique()))`, to get a result like `'en,fr'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clean and sort.
2. Group and select.
3. Collect unique labels and convert them to a string.
4. Rename the column, if needed.

   ```
   df.dropna().sort_values('language')\
           .groupby('id')['language']\
           .unique().str.join(',')\
           .reset_index().rename(columns={'language': 'subs'})
   #   id   subs
   #0   1  en,fr
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.dropna().groupby('id')['language'].unique().reset_index().rename(columns={'language':'subs'})
```

Desired result

```
    id  subs
0   1   [en, fr]
```